# there's a way to do an event before the click event

Tags: c#, winforms

i have plenty of buttons but i have modified them so each button will need to clear the textBox to be fully functional.  However, I don't know how to call the native click event of the button. I've tried to put `btnObj.PerformClick()` but it doesn't work.

```
foreach(object objObject in Controls)
{
    if (objObject is Button)
    {
        (Button)btnObj = (Button)objObject;
        btnObj.Click += (sender,e) =>
        {
           mainTextBox.Clear();
           // how to call the native click button?
        }
    }
}
```

if I dont't edit the code, the mainTextBox never clear.

Comment: What you are trying to do? Do you want main text box to be cleared when any button pressed?

Comment: I fail to see what you're trying to get it to do.  You don't need to do *anything* for the other event handlers to run.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky yeah, it's what I want

Comment: It looks like you're trying to assign a click event handler to the button that clears the text box and then clicks the button again. That doesn't make any sense. If you need to clear the textbox before other click event handlers do their work, you should clear the text box at the beginning of those event handlers.

Comment: @Domix24 Well, that's happening already.  What's the problem?

Comment: You can check for "MouseDown" (click button down) event, that is before "Click" event.

Comment: @Domix24 looks like you want to **recursively** run some code? Why do you want to do so? Please make it clear with some more explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom button which invokes some action before raising Click event handler:

```
public class ButtonWithOverture : Button
{
    public Action Overture { get; set;}        

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Overture != null)
            Overture();

        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Use this buttons instead of simple buttons. You will be able to add specific actions this way:

```
foreach(var button in Controls.OfType<ButtonWithOverture>())    
    button.Overture = () => mainTextBox.Clear();
```

**BUT** better consider to change logic of your application. Think about why you should clear this textbox every time. Maybe its better to simply clear textbox at the beginning of Click event handler. To avoid code duplication (e.g. if you will need to do some other preparations on your form) you can move this action into separate method:

```
 private void ClearControls()
 {
      mainTextBox.Clear();
 }
```

And call it from each Click event handler. At least this will be clear for other developers.

Comment: what is the `()` on that line : `button.Overture = () => mainTextBox.Clear();`

Comment: @Domix24 that's a definition of [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) which does not accepts any arguments

Comment: +1 for the variable names in your new type.

Answer (score -1):

There are some issues with your code such as how you declare your variable.  I belive this is what you are looking for

```
        foreach(object objObject in Controls)
        {
            if (objObject is Button)
            {
                Button btnObj = (Button)objObject;
                btnObj.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    mainTextBox.Clear();
                    btnObj.PerformClick();
                    // how to call the native click button?
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: this will make an infinite loop, i've tried it

Comment: well you see that is the problem, you only gave use a portion of the code.  You should put the full method up that way there is no guessing that this is a click event that you are calling this from.